# Getting error while using highcharts in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am trying highcharts. I created new angular app via cli and installed highcharts and highcharts-angular. I copied code from their github page. In the first run i am getting following errors.

```
ERROR in node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts(128972,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PlotNetworkDataLabelsFormatterCallbackFunction'.
node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts(128982,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PlotNetworkDataLabelsFormatterCallbackFunction'.
node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts(128987,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PlotNetworkDataLabelsTextPath'.
node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts(128992,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PlotNetworkDataLabelsTextPath'.
node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts(136653,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PlotPackedBubbleDataLabelsFormatterCallbackFunction'.
node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts(136658,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PlotPackedBubbleDataLabelsTextPath'.node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts(237720,14): 
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SeriesOrganizationNodesLayoutValues'.
```

I installed highcharts from npm using

> npm install highcharts-angular --save

and

> npm install highcharts --save

then i imported HighchartsChartModule  in app.module.ts and imports array from highcharts-angular. in app.component.ts and app.component.html i added example code from their [github](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#installing) page.

I am getting above error. Am i supposed to install any plugins or dependencies?

Comment: Can you add a StackBlitz example? Here is a working [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zigdgf). The above were the only two packages that I needed to install.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We're having the same issue. Highcharts released 7.1.0 today 7 hours ago. Since then we can't build using 7.1.0. If we lock to 7.0.3 builds fine. Hopefully someone there will see this and a 7.1.1 will be out today.

I also added an [issue to their repo here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10463).